# Securely Sideloading In-House Apps

Tags: security, apk, side-loading

I am working in a secure environment where we do not have wireless communication of any kind, so the only way of installing an app on our Android devices is to sideload it - the original sideloading, over a MTP USB connection.  I would like to mitigate the inherent risks associated with sideloading by only installing apps whose signatures are verified using our public key.  I am working with Android 8.1+, so I get the relatively safer opt-in per app setup.  Is there any way of letting Android know to (only) install apps that my organization has signed?

Comment: Do you use an Mobile Device Management (MDM) system to be able to apply policies onto the devices?

Comment: Currently no.  I'm not aware of any MDMs that work without wireless capabilities, do you know of one?

Comment: So your devices do not have Wifi and they do not have a mobile connection? You did not mention that in your question. Have you thought about running an isolated Wifi hotspot for configuring the devices (a hotspot that just allows to connect to an isolated PC with a web server).

Comment: Edited, clarified.  No wireless communication of any kind; the only means of data transfer is via USB (MTP in particular).